# How do I chain CAAffineTransforms in one animation?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation

I am trying to make the sprite bob as he walks, but no matter what I do it either bobs up and stays, or it does both animations at the same time and you don't actually see the movement. Below I have posted the code I have currently. Can someone please correct me?

I also tried using Animation delegates and using the animationDidStop, but it didn't seem to work either.

```
- (void)walkAnimation {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:2];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:TRUE];
    CGAffineTransform bobUP = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -10);
    //CGAffineTransform bobDOWN = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, +10);
    //CGAffineTransform bob = CGAffineTransformConcat(bobUP, bobDOWN);
    _spriteLayer.affineTransform = bobUP;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    _spriteLayer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot tie those two transforms together in one animation the way you are approaching it. That CGAffineTransformConcat creates a transform that represents doing one transform after the other. The first one translates -10 for the y, then the second one translates +10 for the y. If you do them one after the other you are back where you started. When you assign the resulting transform to the sprite layer, you just tell it not to move at all.

You have two options to achieve what you are looking for:

Option 1: Take a look at keyframe animations (look up CAKeyframeAnimation). These will let you specify the state of properties at different points through the animation. This would probably take a little more learning, but the end result will probably be more readable and maintainable.

Option 2: Have two animations - one for each translation. At the end of each animation, if you want the bobbing to continue, trigger the other animation. This can be confusing and tough to keep up with if you need to make changes later.

Also, either way, I would suggest using a constant for your translation value. Magic numbers will also make future changes require more effort. You should also move toward using block animations for UIView animation (look up animateWithDuration:animations:)